# View 'UPDATE' statements in Django Debug Toolbar (SQL panel)

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I am using Django Debug Toolbar with my project. I am looking to view all SQL statements that are made by the app. Currently, only SELECT statements are shown. Is there a way to enable UPDATE and other statements?

Comment: Try Use the `django-sqlparse`

Comment: As an alternative or in addition?

Comment: Use as  an addition

Comment: I have it installed. Probably came as a dependency. Doesn't seem to help. I googled 'django debug toolbar sql' in images and it only seemss to be showing select queries. So maybe that's intended?